# where does the stack widget make its entry in flutter for the following case

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have two containers that are supposed to stretch out on a screen in a column. On top of these containers I want to put a card on top or another piece of material.
The code I have looks like

```
  Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack widget should contain Column and Card widgets.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: new Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: new Container(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Demo]